# Is there a pattern or ratio for jpg image filesize in relation to image size?

Tags: image, performance, image-resizing, dimensions, filesize

I'm trying to optimize a page which loads a lot of images from S3 and which needs to run on mobile devices, too.

Images are available in S,M,L,XL resolutions, so on a smartphone I'm usually pulling Size M for the grid thumbnail images. These pictures measure: `194x230px` and usually "weigh" around `20k`, which I think is far too much.

**Question:**
If I use Irfan and the RIOT plugin, I can easily shave off 10k from the filesize with the image still looking ok. I'm wondering if there are any guidelines regarding optimal image filesize in relation to image dimensions or is this purely a trial and error process? As a side question, is there any server-side tool, which also uses the RIOT plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: An RGB image with 8 bits per channel containing 194x230 pixels occupies `(194*230*3)/1024` kbytes (which is approximately 131 kbytes) without any compression. There cannot be a formula as simple as you stated because, first: JPEG uses lossy compression and allows different levels of compression; second: it is trivial to construct large images that are very easy to be compressed to a size much smaller than a different much smaller image. I have no idea why you are wondering about the existence of such "guidelines", it is better to get a basic understanding of JPEG inner-working.

Comment: you have a point. :-) Thanks for the info. Need to digest and rethink.